# Journey Builder :- Some contacts are not injecting

Tags: marketing-cloud

We have one Journey whose Entry Source is DE.The DE gets overwritten using a SQL from Automation.
The records which are processed by journey wouldnot be picked up by SQL again.
We have noticed that their are some older records which are not yet injected into Journey and they are coming into Entry DE.
As per Journey Contacts Evaluation tab , Journey rejected these contacts.

What could be the reason for Journey not processing certain records as entry DE is overwritten by SQL on scheduled interval.

How can this issue be resolved?

Comment: It can be your Contacts re-entry mode in Journey settings. Are you by any chance using No re-entry mode?

Comment: We are using option Re-entry anytime.

Comment: Do you have any additional filtering set up on entry criteria in JB?

Comment: No We don't have any additional filter ,We are facing this issue randomly with some records and once the record is not injected then whenever it comes as SQL result output in next automation run it is not injected again into Journey.

Comment: Seems like Journey Builder keeps some historical data. Did you already use the no re-entry mode for this Journey and injected those contacts? If the answer is yes, it's probably the cause for your problem. I'd suggest duplicating your Journey and trying to inject them again..

Comment: Is this anything to do with 'High-water-mark' !..... I guess as you are using the OVERWRITE option, the journey is NOT able to figure out the respective contact has already entered the journey or not!...... Because the OVERWRITE option will delete the hidden attribute set by journey to determine this... If I am confusing please refer this link --- https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pl5dQAA